# launching an android applications from our own view

Tags: android

HIE ALL
i am trying to create a custom home screen in android . i,e in the carousel view . i am able to show the application icons in the carousel view but unable to launch the application . i,e on click of a particular application icon i need to launch the application but i am getting the error(force close). this is error log what i am getting

08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:75)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.performItemClick(CarouselAdapter.java:261)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.onSingleTapUp(Carousel.java:1076)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:557)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.onTouchEvent(Carousel.java:327)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-10 16:04:31.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

[image]

initially i am taking only six images .

please help

thanks in advance
datta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch other application from your app, you need to have it's package name and you can start other app thru;

```
ResolveInfo info;
packageName = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;

Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        if (null != mIntent) {
            try {
                startActivity(mIntent);
            } catch(Exception e) {      }
        }
```

you can get installed package thru:

```
ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
        PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a ClassCastException in line 75 of MainActivity:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
```

Be sure that the parameter you are using really is an Integer.

Comment: @cantona : ya i fixed the issue . how do i combine the icon with the title reapectively.